# .htaccess block wp-json

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I have one normal Wordpress website on which I am trying to block requests to wp-json. I am aware that such requests go via the core of the Wordpress. My request looks like this:
`[root@SV-CentOS-01 ~]# curl -i https://www.website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1`
When I add `RewriteRule ^wp-json.*$ - [L,R=404]` on top of my htaccess I get 404 server response and the API returns me the users of my website. Is there actually a way to achieve what I want via .htaccess or we need to make it the Wordpress way?

Example:

```
[root@SV-CentOS-01 ~]# curl -i https://www.website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2021 14:14:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie,Origin
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <https://www.website.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages, Link
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type
Allow: GET
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=5c07eaa455457ca0ef4b358d016c3b8d; path=/
Upgrade: h2,h2c
Connection: Upgrade
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"id":1,"name":"User One","url":"","description":"","link":"https:\/\/www.website.com\/author\/admin\/","slug":"admin","meta":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.website.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1"}],"collection":[{"href":"https:\/\/www.website.com\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users"}]}}[root@SV-CentOS-01 ~]#
```

Comment: Why `R=404`, why not just [`F`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) for forbidden?

Comment: Behavior is the same with F

Comment: What, still an actual 404 response?

Comment: With [F] you get 403 but again users are listed.

Comment: What do you have ErrorDocument for 404 & 403 set to, if anything? Looks like despite the rewrite, this still gets send into WP's routing mechanism somehow, but I am not exactly sure why that would happen.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [RewriteRule Directive Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) in a per-directory rewrite, you have to use %{REQUEST_URI} in a `RewriteCond`:

> If you wish to match against the full URL-path in a per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule, use the %{REQUEST_URI} variable in a RewriteCond.

So, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/wp-json.*"
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```